# How to Configure SSL on Particular Folder,Not overall Site in iis 7

Tags: iis-7

I have a website for example  www.somesite.com. I want to apply SSL settings on Particular Folder in this site. I followed following steps.

(1) Import Certificate in IIS 7.
(2) Create SSL Bindings.
(3) Select folder in website and set required ssl.

Now my problem is that I want one particular folder to require SSL not overall site. By Following above steps. I can browse whole site with both http and https.

I want whole site to be browsed by only http and the particular folder in website to be browsed using only https.

Like    -http://www.somesite.com    and   -https://www.somesite.com/somefolder

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

IIS **requires** you to do site-level bindings for certificates. In fact, every web server on the planet works this way, it's not possible to bind SSL on a subfolder only.

That doesn't mean it's not possible though. You want to look into a method called "URL ReWriting" - basically, you need to configure your ReWrite rules to detect either HTTP or HTTPS and if they land on a page you want to go HTTP, but they're on HTTPS, then redirect them, and vice versa. This is done invisibly to the user, they will just silently move from HTTP to HTTPS (going from HTTPS to HTTP is not always as seamless, depending on the users browser settings).

IIS7 does have a [native ReWriting](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) module, but I prefer the [ISAPI ReWrite Module](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).